# How to do the count for all unique items

Tags: python

I have attached

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDvxH.png)
i want to : list of unique names of the item and their frequency count (descending order based on the frequency count). using python
Example:
                                          Apples :(23)
                                          Bananas :(16)
                                          Cheese :(9)

Comment: `pandas` has `value_counts()`, and it can read excel or csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to furas comment,
Read the spreadsheet in using pandas and call value_count.

```
import pandas as pd

# Here you would read in your spreadsheet
items = ['Apples','Bananas','Mushrooms','Tomatoes','Apples','Apples','Tomatoes']
ser = pd.Series(items)

# This gives you list output
ser.value_counts()
##Apples       3
##Tomatoes     2
##Mushrooms    1
##Bananas      1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(list_you_want_to_count)
```

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)